# Linq to SQL including a db function

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to recover data from an SQL Server 2016 db.

To start, I have used the POCO class generator to create by datacontext, this contains a definition for the function I want to use.

```
   // Table Valued Functions
        [System.Data.Entity.DbFunction("DbContext", "GetData")]
        [CodeFirstStoreFunctions.DbFunctionDetails(DatabaseSchema = "dbo")]
        public IQueryable<GetDataReturnModel> GetData(long? Id)
        {
            var idParam = new System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter("ID", typeof(long)) { Value = Id.GetValueOrDefault() };

            return ((System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.CreateQuery<GetReturnModel>("[DbContext].[GetData](@ID)", opportunityIdParam);
        }
```

Currently, I have to remove a dataset and then loop through the GetDataReturnedModel to populate the data from this function.

What I would like to do is recover this for each record along with the main request for data.

something like:

```
var data = Entities.Person
                   .Include("Address")
                   .Include(p => p.GetData(p.Id)
                   .ToList();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: A dataset consist of DataTables.  Usually I use a DataTable instead of a DataSet to when querying a database since you always get only one table.  You can get the datatable by using xxx.Table[0].  So you want new var data = {request = "ID", entities = Entities.Person  .Include("Address").Include(p => p.GetData(p.Id).ToList()};

Comment: Would love to set this as the correct solution, thanks for the reply